# wix MSI with custom action DLL dies on wcautil functions

Tags: visual-c++, wix, windows-installer

I'm building a .msi which refers to a custom action DLL written in C++. I can build the custom action DLL in Visual Studio 2010 and everything is fine--references are made to wcautil.h, dutil.h, etc.  When I add the DLL to my .msi, however (it correctly gets a reference in the Binary table, and the keys and such appear reasonable), it dies on the first reference to ExitOnFailure in the custom DLL.  I'm guessing this means that somehow the wcautil.lib is not coming along with the DLL/.msi, but I don't know why that would be--the DLL does include wcautil_2010.lib (and dutil_2010.lib, and msi.lib) in the additional library dependencies list (they were there from the template VS project.)

Anybody know how I can tell if the wcaUtil and dutil are actually present with the .msi? Or what I need to do to make sure they're present so the Wca functions from WiX execute?

Comment: I guess the DLL has to be statically linked. MSI extracts the DLL and runs it, it does not automatically extracts DLLs you depend on. Could it be an uninitialized variable/pointer?

Comment: How does one statically link the DLL? I looked that up a few days ago and people were saying that wasn't possible. I do see that the VS .vcxproj file includes references to the necessary libraries in the 'additional linkage dependencies' area, and the libs are present under $(WIX)sdk\lib.

Comment: @DaveCombs it sounds like your project is already setup to statically link in the wcautil and dutil (the Wix CA project sets this up).  If you're running code up to the first call to `ExitOnFailure` then you're linking ok.  What error are you getting?  How are you sure you're getting to `ExitOnFailure`?  Have you tried attaching a debugger?

Comment: I've been trying to work out how to attach a debugger--the various methods I've tried following so far have all failed. I tried using MsiBreak. I just found that even though the custom action is run during the InstallUISequence (it validates a directory entry), I *can* get a MessageBox up.  I know it's dying on ExitOnFailure because I was able to write a message to a file on the line before the ExitOnFailure, and the line after it had a similar message-writing that didn't show up. I was wondering--it's a DLL, and config type is DLL, but the build flag is /MT, not /MD. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @DaveCombs Have you read [Debugging Custom Actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As suggested, show a message box, and attach the debugger to the process that shows it.

Comment: You can statically link any executable: EXE or DLL. (Yet it does not mean it would use no DLLs at all.) And as heavyd says, most likely you have done it: you code runs, so the issue lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out what's going on.  The WcaInitialize just ahead of the ExitOnFailure was actually returning a bad error code (for some reason I'd read that logging wasn't available, since the DLL runs during the UI phase of the MSI, and mistook that for meaning that all messagebox-stuff was as well.)  The error code indicated that the DLL project didn't contain a Version resource, which seems like a bug, since it was created directly from a template Wix Custom Action DLL template in Visual Studio.)  Once that was fixed, things continued.  Thanks for all the helpful comments!